# trouble installing gorp (GO)

Tags: go, ubuntu-12.04, gorp

Hey I was trying to install [the gorp library](https://github.com/coopernurse/gorp),

```
go get github.com/coopernurse/gorp
```

but got the following error:

```
# github.com/coopernurse/gorp
/usr/lib/go/src/pkg/github.com/coopernurse/gorp/gorp.go:1534: 
method arg.FieldByName is not an expression, must be called
```

is the gorp build just broken? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I just cloned the repo and both the `master` and `development` branch builds fine. Have you tried updating (`git pull`)?

Comment: same error using "go get -u ...".  I will try just standard git clone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use the latest go in order to compile successfully this library.

I just tested with:

> go version go1.2.1 windows/amd64

And that does compile, including the [strange line 1534](https://github.com/coopernurse/gorp/blob/242be3eec6e4d545d0eca24b5dc71236b71ac656/gorp.go#L1534):

```
case arg.Kind() == reflect.Struct && !(arg.Type().PkgPath() == "time" && arg.Type().Name() == "Time"):
    return expandNamedQuery(m, query, arg.FieldByName)
```

Comment: TravisCI (https://travis-ci.org/coopernurse/gorp) shows it building on Go 1.1 as well.

Comment: @elithrar ok, let's wait for the OP to mention what exact version of go was used.

Comment: yeah looks like I had an out-dated version of Go installed.  Must have been the apt-get repository version. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The repository has moved to [github.com/go-gorp/gorp](https://github.com/go-gorp/gorp).

Please install with `go get gopkg.in/gorp.v1`. Use the `import` statement accordingly.

Note that, as the README says:

> This package is compatible with the last 2 major versions of Go, at this time 1.3 and 1.4.